# How to write java code for elasticsearch DSL query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Lets take the following example,

```
    curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
  }
```

Which libraries can we use in order to get the response back from the end point with those body?

Please take note that , it is not likely that GET request will have body. I am aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With elasticsearch < 5.0, you can read the [Java API guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("twitter")
    .setTypes("tweet")
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "kimchy"))
    .get();
```

From 5.0 (and also for previous versions), you can start using the REST Java API [documented here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html).

EDIT: the question was not precise enough. Adding this:

I built my own client at some point but switched to the Official REST one which is much more easier to use. You can see that here: https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/pilato/elasticsearch/crawler/fs/client/ElasticsearchClient.java.

You can see my old home made REST client here https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/blob/c9c00f7da6ecdcc3bfc99bcd530ceb653088f3a4/src/main/java/fr/pilato/elasticsearch/crawler/fs/client/ElasticsearchClient.java

But again, I'd recommend you to use the REST official client. Or be more specific about the issues you have with this.

Comment: The reason why I posted this question is, I want to avoid elastic search client. Do you know any other way rather than using elastic search client?

Comment: Answer Edited. ^^^